# MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 97

Tags: mysql

This is Stored Procedure which has already been running sql server 2005 with its own syntax, and here i have written this in mysql syntax. Everything is ok, but Last End Statement is showing Error.

DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_PREPAREACCOUNTREPORTSBEGIN`(IN `fdate1` DATE, IN `tdate1` DATE, IN `GrossProfit` DOUBLE, IN `NetProfit` DOUBLE, IN `OpeningStock` DOUBLE, IN `ClosingStock` DOUBLE, IN `DiffInBalance` DOUBLE, IN `dc` VARCHAR(25))
BEGIN

```
Create temporary table if not exists Trading
        (Ac_code bigint, AcName varchar(255),Amount float,DC varchar(20),seq int) ENGINE=MEMORY;
insert into Trading SELECT  ledger_master.Ac_code, ledger_master.Ac_name,
                (select case  tmp_closingbalance.Dr when 0 then tmp_closingbalance.Cr else tmp_closingbalance.Dr end),  (select case  tmp_closingbalance.Dr when 0 then 'cr' else 'dr' end),sequence
FROM ledger_master INNER JOIN tmp_closingbalance ON ledger_master.Ac_code = tmp_closingbalance.ac_code INNER JOIN accountgroup ON ledger_master.Group_code = accountgroup.Group_code
where accountgroup.position='t' order by sequence;
set @GrossProfit := 0;
set @GrossProfit := (select ifnull(sum(Amount),0) from Trading where DC='dr') - (select ifnull(sum(Amount),0) from Trading where DC='cr');
        if(@GrossProfit >0) 
        THEN    
        insert into Trading values(0,'GROSS PROFIT',  (@GrossProfit),'cr',9999 );
        else if(@GrossProfit <0)
        then
        insert into Trading values(0,'GROSS PROFIT',  -(@GrossProfit),'dr',9999 );
         end if;
Create temporary table if not exists PL
        (Ac_code bigint,AcName varchar(255),Amount float,DC varchar(20),seq int) ENGINE=MEMORY;
insert into PL 
SELECT    ledger_master.Ac_code, ledger_master.Ac_name,
                (select case  tmp_closingbalance.Dr when 0 then tmp_closingbalance.Cr else tmp_closingbalance.Dr end),
                (select case  tmp_closingbalance.Dr when 0 then 'cr' else 'dr' end),sequence
FROM         ledger_master INNER JOIN
                      tmp_closingbalance ON ledger_master.Ac_code = tmp_closingbalance.ac_code INNER JOIN
                      accountgroup ON ledger_master.Group_code = accountgroup.Group_code
where accountgroup.position='p' order by sequence;
        if (@GrossProfit >0)
        then
        insert into PL values(0,'BY GROSS PROFIT',  (@GrossProfit),'dr',9999 );
        else if (@GrossProfit <0)
        then
        insert into PL values(0,' BY GROSS PROFIT',  -(@GrossProfit),'cr',9999 );
        end if;
set @NetProfit := 0;
set @NetProfit := (select ifnull(sum(Amount),0) from PL where DC='dr') - (select ifnull(sum(Amount),0) from PL where DC='cr');
        if(@NetProfit >0)
        then    
insert into PL values(0,'TO NET PROFIT',  (@NetProfit),'cr',9999 );
else if(@NetProfit <0)
then
insert into PL values(0,'TO NET PROFIT',  -(@NetProfit),'dr',9999 );
end if;

Create temporary table if not exists Balancesheet
        (Ac_code bigint,AcName varchar(255),Amount float,DC varchar(20),seq int) ENGINE=MEMORY;
insert into Balancesheet 
SELECT     ledger_master.Ac_code,ledger_master.Ac_name,
                (select case  tmp_closingbalance.Dr when 0 then tmp_closingbalance.Cr else tmp_closingbalance.Dr end),  (select case  tmp_closingbalance.Dr when 0 then 'cr' else 'dr' end),sequence
FROM  ledger_master INNER JOIN tmp_closingbalance ON ledger_master.Ac_code = tmp_closingbalance.ac_code INNER JOIN accountgroup ON ledger_master.Group_code = accountgroup.Group_code
where accountgroup.position='b' order by sequence;

insert into Balancesheet values(0,'PROFIT & LOSS A/C',-(@NetProfit),'cr',9999);
set @DiffInBalance := 0;
select @DiffInBalance := ((select ifnull(sum(Amount),0) from Balancesheet where DC='dr') - ( select ifnull(sum(Amount),0) from Balancesheet where DC='cr'));

delete from tmp_prepareaccountreports; 
insert into tmp_prepareaccountreports select Ac_code,AcName,Amount,DC,seq,1 as types from Trading order by  types,seq;
insert into tmp_prepareaccountreports select Ac_code,AcName,Amount,DC,seq,2 as types from PL order by  types,seq;
insert into tmp_prepareaccountreports select Ac_code,AcName,Amount,DC,seq,3 as types from Balancesheet order by types,seq;
```

End$$
DELIMITER ;

Comment: This is stored procedure.  Last END statement is 97th Line. I am not getting which type of error is showing.. All Syntax errors were removed already. Please help me with this.

Comment: Do you know how to use DELIMITER? Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Comment: Also, please fix your procedure name. Do you really want your procedure name to be `sp_PREPAREACCOUNTREPORTSBEGIN\nCreate temporary table if not ex`?

Comment: Please have a look once again , i have updated this stored procedure,                
  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 64.    Line No. 64 means before END$$ statement. but I don't see any syntax error there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ELSEIF not ELSE if please review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html

Comment: Yes, Thank You So Much Sir, I have updated it, and finally my stored procedure created successfully.